# System Error after installing R package

Tags: r, dll, windows-8, rstudio

I am running R 3.2.2 on Windows 8. After installing R packages, `rattle` and `rpart.plot` in RStudio an error message propped up in a separate panel.

```
Rterm.exe - System Error. 
  The program can't start because libatk-1.0-0.dll is missing from your computer. 
  Try reinstalling the program to fix this problem.
```

Does anybody have any clue as to what this means and how to fix this?

Comment: The installation was actually performed in RStudio, using the code install.packages. So, I don't believe there's a run as admin option :/

Comment: Sorry, I misread your question.

Comment: How about reading http://datamining.togaware.com/survivor/Installation_Details.html?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Thank you all for your inputs. I managed to figure it out.

The problem arose as a result of missing GTK+ file. I'm not exactly sure what GTK+ really is, but I know that GTK+ is a preliminary file needed to install the Rattle Package. Here's the step I took to download the GTK+ file.

1. First, remove all the tabs opened in RStudio.
2. Use install.packages to download Rattle package. A window should pop up asking to see if you want to download GTK+. Click Yes.
3. Restart RStudio.

Answer (score 3):

I tried closing all the tabs and installing rattle but no pop up appear for me. I then tried installing the package "RGTK2" (fyi, my R studio is version 3.2.0) and after completing this installation, the error message can be closed off.

I restarted Rstudio and the rterm.exe error didn't appear anymore.

Answer (score 3):

I had this issue.

1) Close all open source code tabs

2) `install.packages("RGtk2")`

I didn't even need to restart R-Studio

Comment: Of all answers provided in this post - I was able to replicate this answer.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to add a variation of this error. The error only appeared when using RStudio and not in the RGui. I followed Daniel Lee's answer but with no luck at first, but it pointed me in the right direction. I closed RStudio and opened The R console (RGui), and decided to uninstall the rattle package first, and then reinstalled it again. I never got the pop-up asking about downloading the GTK+. It was only when I specifically tried to run rattle: `rattle()` that rattle complained that the it could not find the GTK+ and prompted me to download and install it. As it turned out I had already downloaded this via another source, so rattle could not install it as it was already installed and was presented with the following warning:

```
Warning messages:
1: Failed to load RGtk2 dynamic library, attempting to install it. 
2: In dir.create(config_path, recursive = TRUE) :
  'C:\Users\[me]\Documents\R\win-library\3.3\RGtk2\gtk\x64\etc\gtk-2.0' already exists
```

I then attempted to start rattle, which was successful. I then started up RStudio and again fire up rattle again with success, and the error `libatk-1.0-0.dll is missing` has now disappeared.

Current setup: R version 3.3.0, RStudio version 0.99.896

Comment: Your suggestion worked for me t0o. Using RGui to install and launch `rattle` is the key.

Answer (score 1):

Try uninstalling the rattle package, then it will prompt to install GTK+. Install that and then cancel the uninstall of the rattle package. Quit R studio and restart it. The libtak error will disappear.

Answer (score 1):

I would only get this error when running RStudio.  I did close all my RStudio tabs and cleared the workspace as suggested by others.  Installing rattle from RStudio would still produce the error. For me, it looks like RStudio could not install RGtk2 due to some permissions issue (i.e. Access Denied with removing the old RGtk2).

I had to manually delete rattle and RGtk2 folders from my R library folder (for me it was in my users folder My Documents\R\win-library\3.3).  Then from Rgui (NOT RStudio), I did install.packages("rattle"). This also installed RGtk2 without any permissions issues.  The error is now gone.

Answer (score 0):

Incase if it has occured from installing the rattle package in R,Just uninstall the package using remove.packages() and restart the R session. The error dissapears :)

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question:
Does anybody have any clue as to what this means ?

It happens in RStudio and is related to `rattle` which uses `RGtk2`.  - 
This problem is because you had order version of `RGtk2` installed (likely 2.20.30), which was the highest possible version for earlier version of RStudio (likely 1.0.44 or earlier) and which is required for `rattle`. Now when you installed new version of RStudio (1.0.143),  it is not compatible with older  `RGtk2` version. Once you install `RGtk2` again (just from Tools menu or run `install.packages("RGtk2")` in RStudio) , it will overwrite the old version of `RGtk2` with newest (2.20.33 version), which is now compatible with 1.0.143 version of RStudio, and this fixes the problem.